# BinaryFormatter Exception on Parsing

Tags: c#

I have an array of bytes that i want to cast to some generic type T, but specifically to a struct.

```
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 8, Pack = 1)]
public struct PcdHeader
{
    public ushort FormatVersion;
    public ushort TableCount;
    public ushort CRC;
    public ushort Reserved;
}
```

Here is my cast code

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arr)) // arr is byte[] == sizeof(T)
{
    return (T)bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

The return is throwing the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.

I have verified that the size of the struct is the same size as the array. Am i missing something with the intended behavior? I have even tried making sure that position is at zero before doing the deserialization.

Comment: Why do you think `Deserialize` can help with your task?

Comment: You have to Serialize first. This is not `fread` from C.

Comment: @PetSerAl Because i am technically deserializing the data that is stored in a byte array and based on other similar situations for data conversion like this, this is the answer i have seen given, however no mention on this error has occurred.

Comment: @leppie I am getting the data from a serialized file, specifically an intel hex file that i have parsed into a byte array. What other extra serialization needs to occur?

Comment: I suggest you iterate over the array then and construct it manually, easiest from what I can see.

Comment: @lucasbrendel `Deserialize` return object and you casting it to `T`. This cast will only succeed if `Deserialize` actually return instance of `T`. But how it should know instance of which type it should return? `Deserialize` is intended to parse data in one particular format: data what you get from `Serialize` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself using a reply from this link:

[Solution](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/249770-byte-structure)

Slightly modifying it to my needs I ended up with this

```
if (typeof(T).IsValueType && !typeof(T).IsPrimitive)
{
    IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(numBytes);
    Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, buffer, numBytes);
    object retobj = Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(T));
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
    return (T)retobj;
}
```

Comment: If your problem is solved then please either delete the question or mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @EricLippert I will mark it as accepted once i am allowed. I can't until tomorrow since it is my own answer.

Comment: You do not need to allocate separate unmanaged buffer and copy data here. You can: `GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(arr, GCHandleType.Pinned); IntPtr buffer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(); ...; handle.Free();`